# How to enter a chroot without using sudo?

Tags: sudo, chroot

Is it possible to enter a chroot without using sudo? If so, how? I've tried googling, but all I get are results about crouton.

Comment: why you don't want `sudo`?

Comment: The full reason is that I want to set up multiple minecraft servers on a single machine, each within its own chroot. I administrate one, but want to allow other people to administrate the others. They would need root privileges to do so, so thus the choice for chroot. However, I don't want them to have root privileges for the entire system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at the [schroot](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/schroot) [image: Install schroot] package. It provides a way to grant user access to one or more chroots on your system. The configuration allows each chroot to be accessed by only certain users or groups and allows bind-mounting of directories from the host system into each chroot as desired.

Once it is configured, it is easy for an ordinary user with no root privileges to run

```
schroot -c chroot1 -- cmd ...
```

For some more description and examples of how to configure schroot, read

- [Schroot - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot)
- [schroot - chroot for any users](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/566/schroot_-_chroot_for_any_users)

Answer (score 2):

These days chrooting without root-permissions is possible with `unshare` command provided by [mount namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/689856/).

## Plain Unshare

Suppose you want to chroot into `~/Projects/my-backup` directory, and run inside it the `~/Projects/my-backup/bin/bash` binary . So you run:

```bsh
$ unshare -mr chroot ~/Projects/my-backup/ /bin/bash
```

Here:

- `-m` means you can use `mount --bind` inside the new chroot *(note that mounts will not be visible to the outside world, only to your chroot)*
- `-r` makes it look as if you are root inside the chroot
- `chroot …` is the usual chroot command.

Possible pitfalls:

1. Make sure you have environment variables set correctly. For example, upon chrooting into an Ubuntu from Archlinux I was getting errors like `bash: ls: command not found`. Turned out, my `$PATH` did not contain `/bin/` *(on Archlinux it's a symlink to `/usr/bin/`)*, so I had to run:

   ```bsh
   PATH=$PATH:/bin/ unshare -mr chroot ~/Projects/my-backup/ /bin/bash
   ```
2. Note that `/proc` or `/dev` filesystems won't get populated, so running a binary that requires them will fail. There is a `--mount-proc` option, but it doesn't seem to be accessible to a non-root user.
3. `chown` won't work unless you do some complicated setup with `newuidmap` and `newgidmap` commands.

## Buildah Unshare

This has advantage compared to plain `unshare` in that it takes care of the needed setup for `chown` command to start working. You only need to make sure you have defined the ranges in `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` for your user.

You run it as:

```
$ buildah unshare chroot ~/Projects/my-backup/ /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do this , some easier and some more difficult. Some more secure, some less secure. And then there are all the opinions about all the options.

IMO , chroot are the least secure and the most work to maintain. There are scripts and packages to try to lessen the work, but they remain, IMO, the least secure. There is no real way to manage resource allocation with chroot.

LXC is next, and you can manage LXC with graphical tools, both graphical (virt-manager) and web tools exist. The problem, IMO, with LXC is that it is in rapid development. Still LXC is a bit more secure and easier to assign resources then chroot, although doing so is a bit complex and requires knowledge of cgroups.

I would suggest openvz. The problem with openvz is that it is not supported on Ubuntu hosts. You can, however, use Fedora, CENTOS, RHEL or Proxmox. Proxmix is based on Debian so most similar to Ubuntu. All these OS have graphical tools to manage guests and allocate resources. Proxmox is web based and will transition to LXC once the Proxmox project considers LXC to be stable enough for "production" environments.

You could use XEN, vbox, or kvm, but all these options have a bit higher overhead then chroot/lxc/openzv. Management is easier as they all have graphical tools, all are secure, all allow resource allocation.

IMO, Proxmox is going to be the easiest, most secure option. Second choice would be LXC on Ubuntu using virt-manager.

Answer (score 0):

You could install all of them a lxc container with all needed programms, including a shell, the minecraft server and a ssh-daemon or a full linux system.

You would have to start the container with its sshd and minecraft-server as root, but the users of it would be restricted to your `lxc.rootfs`.

If you have enough IP-adresses you could assign each of them one of those, otherwise you could start the sshd and the minecraft server on mutual exclusive ports.